# How to preprocess and feed data to keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I have a dataset with two columns, path and class. I'd like to fine tune VGGface with it.

```
dataset.head(5):


    path            class
0   /f3_224x224.jpg red
1   /bc_224x224.jpg orange
2   /1c_224x224.jpg brown
3   /4b_224x224.jpg red
4   /0c_224x224.jpg yellow
```

I'd like to use these paths to preprocess images and feed to keras. My preprocessing functions is below:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img

def prep_image(photo):
    img = image.load_img(path + photo, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = utils.preprocess_input(x, version=1)
    return x
```

I prepare my datasets with the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

path = list(dataset.columns.values)
path.remove('class')
X = dataset[path]
y = dataset['class']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

I train my model with the following code:

```
nb_class = 4
hidden_dim = 512

vgg_model = VGGFace(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
last_layer = vgg_model.get_layer('pool5').output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
x = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='relu', name='fc6')(x)
x = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='relu', name='fc7')(x)
out = Dense(nb_class, activation='softmax', name='fc8')(x)
custom_vgg_model = Model(vgg_model.input, out)
custom_vgg_model.compile(

        optimizer="adam",
        loss="categorical_crossentropy"
    )

custom_vgg_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=16)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

However i get value error because i can't figure out how to preprocess images and feed the arrays. How can i transform the paths from X_train/test dataframes and replace them with the output of prep_image function?

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (50297, 1)
```

So the shape should be (50297, 224, 224, 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X_train, X_test are basically just path names it seems. In your data preparation step you just need to modify your code like that adding those last two lines.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

path = list(dataset.columns.values)
path.remove('class')
X = dataset[path]
y = dataset['class']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
X_train = np.array([prep_image(path)[0] for path in X_train])
X_test = np.array([prep_image(path)[0] for path in X_test])
```